# Prove that $\|\boldsymbol{e}_{1}- UU^\intercal\boldsymbol{e}_1\|_2 = \sqrt{1-\|U^\intercal\boldsymbol{e}_1\|_2^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

It looks easy but somehow I can not proof the below equation, thanks in advance
$$\|\boldsymbol{e}_{1}- UU^\intercal\boldsymbol{e}_1\|_2 =  \sqrt{1-\|U^\intercal\boldsymbol{e}_1\|_2^2}$$ where U is a $m \times n$ matrix with orthonormal columns (**NOT SQUARE**), $\boldsymbol{e}_1$ denotes $[1, 0, 0, 0,... 0]^\intercal$ and $\| .\|_2$ the Euclidean norm.

Comment: If $U$ is orthonormal then $UU^{T} = I$ and your left hand side is $0$

Comment: U is not square here.

Comment: ...and then how can it be orthonormal??

Comment: I should've said U is an m by n matrix with orthonormal columns

Comment: @user2650091 Yes, an orthogonal matrix is a square matrix by definition, namely a square matrix which columns form an orthonormal system

Comment: Title of the question should be "Prove that $\|\boldsymbol{e}_{1}- UU^\intercal\boldsymbol{e}_1\|_2 =  \sqrt{1-\|U^\intercal\boldsymbol{e}_1\|_2^2}$". Your notation here seems unconventional, you should clarify what you mean.

Comment: Title updated. sorry where is ambiguous or confusing? I will try to update

Answer (score 1):

Note that $U^TU=I$, so
$$
\|e - UU^Te\|^2 = 1 - 2e^TUU^Te + e^TUU^TUU^Te=1 - 2e^TUU^Te + e^TUU^Te
= 1-e^TUU^Te
$$
for unit vectors $e$.

Comment: great!!! thanks alot